# What is the best way to formulate a check in/check out status sheet similar to a library database?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to build a checkout system for devices at work using spreadsheets and google forms. The google forms work wonderfully, and I'm able to get all the data I need in a spreadsheet that I can look through manually if a device turns up missing. I was hoping the process of taking this data and creating a sheet that would give the status of device as "IN" or "OUT" would be simple, but I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for.

From Google forms it goes into a sheet with timestamp, device, and who checked it out.
There is a separate form and sheet when checking the device back in.

From there I created a new "STATUS" sheet that I referenced the other two to get the most recent time stamp, which device, and who checked it out.

I'm trying to reference the cells with those changing values to trigger the cells next to each device as "IN" or "OUT" but I can only have one IN and one OUT at a time.

[image: SheetLayout]

In this sheet I am using VLOOKUP to find the latest device checked out using
=VLOOKUP(MAX(TIMEOUT),CHECKOUT!A2:B,2,FALSE)

To change the values that are currently FALSE I am referencing the cell with the returned value of the VLOOKUP using
=IF(E4=C24,"OUT",IF(E11=C24,"IN"))

However, whenever I check out another device it changes the next device OUT, but returns the previous checkout to FALSE.

I know nesting functions can screw sheets up when used incorrectly, so I was hoping for some guidance because I'm not too good at this apparently. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.

Sorry for the delayed response.

I have been trying to get a google form to link to the sample sheet but can't seem to get it to work. Will have to manually create the named ranges as soon as I can.

Here is what I have so far. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Updated Solution

Uses the sheets named [`blind_STATUS`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit#gid=499974875) , [`blind_IN`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit#gid=1870589079) ,and [`blind_OUT`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit#gid=388185969)

[`blind_STATUS`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit#gid=499974875) sheet has:

- A single entry for each unique `Device`,
- the device's current `Status`,
- the `Timestamp` associated with the status,
- the duration a device has been `Out (hrs)`,
- the ability to do some primary and secondary `sorting` via drop-menus,
- the current sort is rendered at top of the page to avoid confusion with defaults, redundant and/or contradictory options, etc.

###### Sample Status Page <sup>[ [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit#gid=499974875) ]</sup>

| Sorting by "STATUS ▼" | then by | "OUT (HRS)▲" |  |  |  | Sort [ default ▲ /▼ ] | By | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | **Primary** [ Timestamp ▼ ] | **Status** | **Descending** |
| **Timestamp** | **Device** | **Employee** | **Status** | **Out (hrs)** |  | ***Optional*** [ ▲ ] | **Out (hrs)** | **Ascending** |
| Jan-10-2023 6:07 AM | TC26-05 | Wheeler, Lena | OUT | 66.09 |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-10-2023 5:07 AM | TC26-21 | Maldonado, Annabelle | OUT | 67.09 |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-09-2023 6:10 PM | TC26-10 | Morgan, Daphne | OUT | 78.04 |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-08-2023 6:05 PM | TC26-23 | Mathews, Lamont | OUT | 102.13 |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-10-2023 5:08 AM | TC26-20 | Villanueva, Barbara | IN |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-08-2023 6:20 PM | TC26-22 | Bishop, Saniyah | IN |  |  |  |  |  |

<kbd>Sample Status Page</kbd>
[image]

##### Formula

```
=SORT(
   BYROW(_MYSORT2({_MYSORT2(_out, "OUT");_MYSORT2(_in, "IN")},), 
         LAMBDA(_r, IF(INDEX(_r,,4)="OUT",
               {_r,(NOW()-INDEX(_r,,1))*24}, _r))),
   IFERROR(MATCH(_byPri,_cols,0),1),
   IF(_ordPri="Ascending",1,0),
   IFERROR(MATCH(_bySec,_cols,0),IFERROR(MATCH(_ordSec,_cols,0),1)),
   IF(_ordSec="Descending",0,1)
   )
```

<kbd>Formula</kbd>
[image: Formula]

##### Named Ranges

| Name | Range | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| _cols | blind_STATUS!A3:E3 | Column Headings |
| _in | blind_IN!A2:C1000 | Checkin Data Columns |
| _out | blind_OUT!A2:C1000 | Checkout Data Columns |
| _byPri | blind_STATUS!H2 | Primary Sort Column |
| _bySec | blind_STATUS!H3 | Secondary Sort Column |
| _ordPri | blind_STATUS!I2 | Primary Sort Order |
| _ordSec | blind_STATUS!I3 | Secondary Sort Order |

[image]

##### Named Function

Solution uses a `Named Function` for the custom `SORTN` to reduce the length and complexity of the parent formula.

There are two options below based on the possible source data.

**`_MYSORT`   (v1)**
Simpler and requires the source data include a field identifying if coming from check-in or check-out.

| Timestamp | Device | Employee | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/8/2023 18:00:00 | TC26-23 | Melton, Malia | "IN" |

```
_MYSORT =Lambda(x, 
         SORTN(SORT(x,1,0),COUNTA(INDEX(x,,1)),2,2,1))
         (FILTER(_in, INDEX(_in,,1)<>""))
```

**`_MYSORT2`   (v2)**
Longer but can be used regardless if the source data includes a field identifying if coming from check-in or check-out, or if it does not.

| Timestamp | Device | Employee |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/8/2023 18:00:00 | TC26-23 | Melton, Malia |  |

```
_MYSORT2 =BYROW(LAMBDA(x, SORTN(SORT(x,1,0),
                COUNTA(INDEX(x,,1)),2,2,1))
                (FILTER(_data, INDEX(_data,,1)<>"")), 
          LAMBDA(y, IF(_label<>"",{y, _label},y)))
```

##### Benefit in Practice

***you can use this formula***

```
=_MYSORT2({ _MYSORT2(_out, "OUT");
            _MYSORT2(_in, "IN")
           },)
```

***as a replacement for this formula***

```
=LAMBDA(x, SORTN(SORT(x,1,0),COUNTA(INDEX(x,,1)),2,2,1))
 ( BYROW(
     {
       BYROW(
         LAMBDA(x, SORTN(SORT(x,1,0),COUNTA(INDEX(x,,1)),2,2,1))
         (FILTER(_out, INDEX(_out,,1)<>"")),
         LAMBDA(y, {y, "OUT"})
       );

       BYROW(
         LAMBDA(x, SORTN(SORT(x,1,0),COUNTA(INDEX(x,,1)),2,2,1))
         (FILTER(_in, INDEX(_in,,1)<>"")),
         LAMBDA(y, {y, "IN"}))
      },

     Lambda(x, SORTN(SORT(x,1,0),COUNTA(INDEX(x,,1)),2,2,1)))
  )
```

[image]  
[image]

---

###### NOTE

My first approach did not use `SORTN`, but rather `MAXIFS`.  In trying to further simplify the formula and add secondary dynamic `Sort By` options, I switched from `MAXIFS` to `SORTN` inspired by [doubleunary's approach](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168667/), and he should be given credit for [that answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168667/).

My older formula that I updated:

```
=SORT(
   BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(_oDev,ROW(_oDev)>1)), 
      LAMBDA (r, IF(r<>"", 
         IF(MAXIFS(_oTime, _oDev, r)>MAXIFS(_iTime, _iDev, r),
            { r, "OUT", MAXIFS(_oTime, _oDev, r), 
              INDEX(_oEmp, MATCH(MAXIFS(_oTime, _oDev, r),_oTime)),
              (NOW()-MAXIFS(_oTime, _oDev, r))*24 },
            { r, "IN",MAXIFS(_iTime, _iDev, r), 
              INDEX(_iEmp, MATCH(MAXIFS(_iTime, _iDev, r),iTime)) }),))),
   IFERROR(MATCH(_sortBy,_headings,0),1),
   IF(_sortOrd="Descending",0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all devices that appear in `CHECKOUT` and `CHECKIN`, so that only the most recent status of each device is shown, use `sortn()`, like this:

```
=sortn( 
  sort( 
    { 
      CHECKOUT!A2:C, left("out", 9 * len(CHECKOUT!A2:A)); 
      CHECKIN!A2:C, left("in", 9 * len(CHECKIN!A2:A)) 
    }, 
    1, false  
  ), 
  9^9, 2, 
  2, true 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit#gid=287296540).

If you want to see these results in a table like the one in the STATUS tab, use the `vlookup()` function, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup(A2:A24, Solution!B2:D, columns(Solution!B2:D), false) 
  ) 
)
```

See the [STATUS2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQbzF8KooQLyEZrvqTPdIUsK4zyMkx0Ir5kDwor7_Qg/edit#gid=163311207) tab.